# Dried beans, cooked in an acidic sauce, haven't softened enough - can I do anything now?

Tags: beans

I know *why* my beans haven't softened - I was adapting a recipe (that calls for tinned beans) to use dried - and there's vinegar in the sauce.  I soaked an assortment of beans from different packs overnight, and cooked in the slow cooker on high for 8 hours.  That would normally be plenty even in chilli with a fair bit of tomato.  As the beans came from different packs that were fine a week ago, and  were uniformly too firm, I don't reckon it's that the beans are too old.  They were just about edible last night.  A further 12 hours on low overnight softened them a little more, but they're still firmer than I'd like.  The recipe isn't online but it's beans, onion, garlic, spices, treacle and vinegar, similar to a vegetarian Boston Baked Beans.

The solution for next time is easy - add the vinegar when they're nearly cooked - but I made several portions and would like to make the best of what I've cooked.

Is there anything I can do at this stage to make them soften further? Would neutralising the acid and cooking some more help?

Comment: Been there. I have tried baking soda and further cooking without success.

Comment: Wild, no evidence, out of left field idea - I wonder if something similar is happening like if you bring potatoes to almost a boil then switch off. They then retain their structure no matter how long you cook them a second time.

Comment: @Tetsujin possibly, but I never let them cool - when I realised they were barely edible but I was hungry and the rest of my dinner was ready, I just left the slow cooker on, turning it down before bed (and beans normally cook OK on low for about 12 hours)

Comment: Thanks @Jolenealaska.  I may experiment anyway on a small portion but won't rely on it.  Maybe I should drain, mash, and turn into bean burgers!

Comment: @ChrisH - sorry, I meant the end result being similar, rather than the actual cause. par-boil vs acid.

Comment: @Jolenealaska don't you mean 'Bean there' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blender.**

That will get them soft.  Then you can fry the bean paste, like refried beans.

Comment: I did indeed do something very similar, only I added a bit of gram flour and formed it into burgers before frying.  Strangely a few beans that escaped being blended seemed softer - maybe the extra soak, maybe the extra cooking, or maybe the different context affected my perception of the texture

Comment: The psychology of bean eating...  A new frontier!